# How do I take my RMarkdown/Knitr output and embed it into a Wordpress article

Tags: html, r, wordpress, knitr, r-markdown

My RMarkdown file successfully runs via Knitr and I'm given a .html file that executes my code and presents my plot outputs.

For my blog, I just want to utilize the plot output. How can I extract just the plot and embed it into my Wordpress blog.

[EDIT]: the plot i'm generating is an interactive plot_ly plot.

Comment: Oh, you're using a `plot_ly` plot. That's not an image plot. You're going to need to save the widget out (`htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`) and then embed it in an `iframe`.

Comment: Does that command go into the RMarkdown file?

Comment: well, technically it could go there, but it's better to run it interactively IMO.

Comment: alright, do you mind walking me through this. I'm pretty new to R. So, after reading some documentation on `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`, I see that common arguments are _widget_ and/or _file_. I'm not entirely sure what I would put in there for widget but when I put the path to my .html file, i get this error: `Error in x$width : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Comment: nvm, i figured it out. having trouble with the iframe portion now. i have the .html file save on my drive. how do I take that and use iframe to embed it into my WP article.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

and you'll see a `xyz_files` directory in the same directory (with the same name) as your Rmd file. That will have a `figure-html` directory under it and your images will be there standalone.

If you have the latest `rmarkdown` & `knitr` then you should also have retina quality PNGs by default, otherwise do:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina=2)
```
````

at the top of your document (below the yaml header)

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to RMD and Knitr. Should I use that code in the RMarkdown file?

Comment: yes. the first bit is an augmentation of the YAML header. the other bit shld be the first code chunk.

Comment: I tried it and the only difference is a .md file is generated. I don't see the directories that you mention

Comment: pretty much b/c you're using an htmlwidget and not a normal plot. see my comment under your post. `saveWidget()` plus some `iframe` work is in your future.